# Display jQuery colorbox for Rails Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colorbox

I am using gem [`colorbox-rails`](https://github.com/stevo/colorbox-rails) for using color-box in my application:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("add.png"), { action: 'new', controller: 'tourism_packages' }, data: { colorbox_static: true,  colorbox_tourism_package: true }, class: 'action-icons', id: 'create-tour-package' %>
```

to open the color box on a button click. I want to open the colorbox for a rails controller action.

```
def create
  @package = TourismPackage.create(@tourism_package_params)
  @package.creator = current_user

  if @package.save
    redirect_to tourism_packages_path
  else
    flash[:error] = @package.errors.messages
    render :new  # here I want to open the new action as colorbox
  end
end
```

I tried:

```
render :color-box
```

That doesnot work. How can I open the new action in a colorbox without any button click.

Comment: Yes the same gem. What is th eother easier way to implement color-box in rails? Or is there a way I can achieve what I want using this gem only?

Comment: You have contradictory statements in your question. 1. _"I am using ... to open the color box **on a button click**"_. 2. _"How can I open the ... in a colorbox **without** any button click"_.

Comment: The first scenario, I am opening the color box on a button click, which is successful. When I try to open the same without button click, on a controller action, I am not able to do that.

Comment: Well, for starters, `:color-box` is not valid ruby code. So, `render :color-box` won't work. May be change it to `render 'color-box'`.

Comment: I tried and even That did not work. if Color box is not advisable, what is the other options that I can use for bringing modal dialog with some nice styles in a Rails application.